# Clear local storage variable after app is closed from Recent Apps section

Tags: javascript, cordova

How can I clear a local storage variable in a Cordova Android App when the app is cleared from the Recent Apps menu by sliding instead of exiting normally using the back button?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Cordova has an even handler for that.

You can see events supported by Cordova [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html)

You might wanna take a look at pause event and clear Local Storage at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, but it seems that just reseting `localStorage` variable on every app start (`deviceready`) would be equivalent.

Comment: I am restarting the app after click of a button and I am using local storage at that time. So if I exit the app normally and then open it, then only I want the local storage to get erased. But if the app restarts from that button, then I dont want local storage to be erased.

Comment: A workaround would be to set something to the local storage on a click of that button, so on app start you would know if the restart was initiated with that click or not.